# WPS Office create new documents with Japanese name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, microsoft-office, wps

In Ubuntu, I updated WPS Office to version11.1.0.10161 and when I right-click, New Document I see various options with names in Japanese characters, i.e. DOC 文档.doc

Comment: These are chinese characters not japanese.

Comment: That's not the point, whatever characters they are isn't English!

Comment: The point is to be precise as it is influence the title of your question. By the way, these characters means "New Document".